# Accept multiple params in a single PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, post

I have a controller method as this:

```
@PostMapping("/view/{location}")
public ModelAndView view(@PathVariable("location") String location) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    return modelAndView;
}
```

This method is capable of receiving requests like

> "/view/a" or "/view/b" such that pathVariable **location** becomes a or b.

But I want this same method to receive all the requests having /view in their beginning, such that the pathVariable **"location"** holds the rest of the data.

for example

> for a request as **/view/a/b/c**, the pathVariable **location** will become **a/b/c**.

like a file system hierarchy.

Please let me know if such a thing is possible in Spring MVC, and I am very new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [article](http://roufid.com/spring-mvc-path-variable-slash/)

The idea is to map all the paths which start with `/view` to a single controller method by adding `**`, but you'll have to use `HttpServletRequest` instead of `@PathVariable`.

So, in your case, it'll be something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/view/**")
public ModelAndView view(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String pathVariable = extractId(request);         

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    return modelAndView;
}

private String extractId(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String path = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    String bestMatchPattern = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
    return new AntPathMatcher().extractPathWithinPattern(bestMatchPattern, path);
}
```

Also, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470421/pathvariable-in-springboot-with-slashes-in-url)

Answer (score 1):

You could go by the approach shared earlier,

```
@GetMapping(value = "blog/**")
public Blog show(HttpServletRequest request){   
    String id = (String) 
            request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    System.out.println(id);
    int blogId = Integer.parseInt(id);
    return blogMockedData.getBlogById(blogId);
}
```

---

Second way is to use RequestParam instead of Path variable.

you will call the api using :

```
http://localhost:8080/blog?input=nabcd/2/nr/dje/jfir/dye
```

controller will look like :

          `@GetMapping(value = "blog")
public Blog show(@RequestParam("input") String input){`

---

If you are certain about the number of slash in your input, you could go with any approach mentioned here [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421061/how-to-handle-requests-that-includes-forward-slashes)