# Allowing a Slash Character In Spring WebFlux Get Requests

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, slash, webflux

I have a spring WebFlux project and it turns out that I need to allow for a Slash in query parameters for a couple API calls.
In Spring MVC you would use the HttpServletRequest to handle that use case like in this example:

[@PathVariable in SpringBoot with slashes in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470421/pathvariable-in-springboot-with-slashes-in-url)

How would you do that with WebFlux?  I can't find any good articles about that online.

Comment: I think you need to encode your params.

Comment: Please note that newbedev is a Stack Exchange scraper; don't link to it. Instead, google the text or title, and find the correct link to the network, instead of giving scrapers more traffic that they don't deserve.